# $z=e^{2\pi i/5}$ solves $1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$

Tags: complex-numbers

What is the best way to verify that
$$1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4=0$$
given $z=e^{2\pi i/5}$?

I tried using Euler's formula before substituting this in, but the work got messy real fast.

Comment: Hint: since $z \neq 1$, you can use the geometric sequence formula (this is a standard trick; keep it in your toolbox)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly(?) $z^5=1$ and $z\ne 1$. Also, $$z^ 5-1=(z-1)(1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4)$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: for $z \neq 1$, we have:

$$ \frac{z^5-1}{z-1}=1+z+z^2+z^3+z^4$$

Now see what happens when you let $z=e^{2\pi i/5}$